# AutoHotkey disable Alt+Tab, Winkey, Ctrl+Alt+Delete for kiosk mode

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I am booting a Windows 8 PC into Chrome with "--kiosk" added to the path so I have kiosk mode enabled. Now I need to disable every key that would allow the user to exit the kiosk mode. So far I have identified:

- All function keys F1 to F12
- Alt-Key (e.g. Alt+Tab)
- Windows Key

Ctrl+Alt+Delete will be disabled by Group Policy (gpedit.msc and then navigating to User Config > Admin Templates > System > Ctrl+Alt+Del options).
Do you see more key combinations that would allow a user to exit other than this?

What script would I need to disable the 3 combinations above and how would I create a prompt for a pin code dialogue in AutoHotkey, like we press Alt+F7 and now we have to enter a 6 digit pin to unlock the keys and Alt+F8 to lock the keys?

Comment: The following post has a more detailed list of keys to block:
https://superuser.com/questions/727072/what-windows-shortcuts-should-be-blocked-on-a-kiosk-mode-pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some other browsers like FireFox and Opera have many keys already locked.

Here is a script to lock some of the keys down. For the <kbd>F1</kbd>..<kbd>F12</kbd>, you will have to fill-in the missing keys... You might have to add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (^Esc::Return)

```
!Tab::Return ; Alt-Tab
!F4::Return ; Alt-F4

F1::Return
F2::Return
......
F11::Return
F12::Return

LWin::Return
RWin::Return
#::Return
```

The easiest way to lock/unlock the keys is with "suspend". You can do that this way.

```
!F7::
InputBox, Code, Unlock,Enter the unlock code.,HIDE
If ErrorLevel
    Return
If (Code = 1234)
    Suspend, On
Return

!F8::
    Suspend, Off
Return
```

P.s. untested code....

You could also add a check every 200 ms or so, to see of your kiosk is indeed "on top" and if not, refocus windows to the kiosk...

Comment: Will it prevent Win+L combo? Just curious.