# Can I make a local user that only runs one program in Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, applocker

I am making an account for my kids to do their math program (a standard windows exe) and I would like to have it be the shell when they log in.  If that is not a thing anymore, I would like to have it be the only program they can run.  And barring that I'd like to prevent them from running Microsoft Edge.  I have been trying applocker, but that both does not work and the Application Indentity service it says it needs does not wamt to be set to automatic in the services snap-in, and I cannot find where it is supposed to be in Group Policy (because it was moved there apparently).  I have tried applocker for edge on bothe the packaged app and the path (in windows/systemapps).

Seems to me, this used to be easy, now it is fairly impossible without creating yet another microsoft account to use parental controls.  I don't want to use parental controls because I want this to be a shared account and all the kids have to do to get onto it is login as "math" with a password so obvious an 8 year old "hacked" it.

Comment: See this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1192612/213131).

Comment: There is no functional difference between a local user and a local user connected to a Microsoft Account.  What works for a local profile will work for a local profile connected to a Microsoft Account

Comment: @ram but I could use parental controls to prevent access to things I don't want this account to get to if I sent it up as a child account.   I just thought it was a little lame to register a child name "math" with microsoft.

Comment: @twisty, I added the shell key to winlogon and it didn't do anything. I configured applocker and it didn't do anything.  I configured the firewall to start a scheduled task to block all internet traffic when logged on as this user and it didn't do anything.   Possibly I'm doing all these things wrong, but I think eventually I'd stumble on one thing that would actually work.

Comment: @PeterTurner - You made no mention of any of that in your question.  The use Parental Controls makes a difference.

Comment: @ram yeah I don't want to use parental controls, that's why I didn't mention it.

Comment: I [assume](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32f6bc8c-cabf-449f-a9f5-08152acea8f5/how-to-block-edge-from-running?forum=win10itprogeneral) you have seen these instructions?

Comment: @ramhound yes, I followed those ones (both as a packaged app and an executable by path) and I'd imagine that'd work, but it's applocker/Group Policy/Application Identity Service that isn't working with Windows 10 Pro.